# Howto compile VLC for ARM

Tags: arm, vlc

When one wants VLC to work on a FriendlyARM device.

What is the best way to compile VLC for ARM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check [blogs.soctel.in](http://blogs.soctel.in). you can find procedure to build the kernel, libraries, build VLC, and streaming using VLC and related information