# Vlc and vlc web plugin on a cubox with arm architecture

Tags: linux, arm, vlc

is possibile to install vlc and the web plugin of vlc on a [Cubox](http://solid-run.com/cubox)?

Wich version of linux is better and you reccomend?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885203/howto-compile-vlc-for-arm/12193385#12193385) i have seen that is possible recompile the source code for the arm architecture but is possibile use vlc on cubox without recompile?

I need to create a Web page that use the VLC web plugin and play some video on a Cubox.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks

Luca

PS: sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.solid-run.com/mw/index.php/CuBox_hardware_specification

Their hardware specs specify it having armv6/armv7 compatiable cores so if the vlc is compiled tor those processors then yes it "should" play. There is only one way to find out and get a hold of their distribution of os (which is just a variant of popular linux distros) and install it in a vm machine that simulates the hardware or get an actual cubox.

http://www.solid-run.com/mw/index.php/Category:Operating_System
List/Comparison of used linux distros

Comment: Hi Patric,
thanks for the answer.
In the list of supported Linux ArchLinux and i have seen in the ArchLinux's repository i found vlc then, in theory, vlc must run on CUBOX.
My "reasoning" is that correct?

thanks again

Luca

Comment: If the listed repo of it is listed for armv6 armv7 then yes it should list what architecture it was built for, ie x86 x64 arm arm6 etc

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=extra from there i do not see any listing of arm architecture so you might have to get a archlinux distro, get the vlc source and cross compile for the arm architecture.

Comment: Hi, cubox support archlinux. is possible that support also arch linux for arm? on arch linux arm website repo i found the latest version of vlc. http://archlinuxarm.org

Comment: yea, thats what it uses is the arm version of archlinux since thats what the processors are.

Comment: ok. in theory cubox+archlinuxarm+vlc for archlinuxarm will work.